# The problem of creating two uploads folders in the image address

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I use the [one user avatar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/one-user-avatar/) plugin

I want to create a folder inside the uploads folder so that users who upload their avatar will be uploaded in that folder. I also put a conditional order that only the avatars are uploaded in the desired folder. There is a problem, the image in the desired folder is uploaded correctly, But when I refresh the page, it shows 2 upload paths in the image address, which makes the image not load.

http://localhost/i/wp-content/**uploads**/**uploads**/avatar/01.jpg

This is my code :

```
function wp_set_custom_upload_folder($uploads) {
    if ( $_FILES['wpua-file'] ) {
        $uploadDir = 'wp-content/uploads/avatar';
        $uploads['path'] = ABSPATH . $uploadDir;
        $uploads['url'] = site_url('/'.$uploadDir);
        $uploads['basedir'] =  ABSPATH . 'wp-content';
        $uploads['baseurl'] =  site_url('/wp-content');
        if (!file_exists($uploads['path'])) {
          mkdir($uploads['path'], 0755, true);
        }
    }
    return $uploads;
} add_filter('upload_dir', 'wp_set_custom_upload_folder');
```

Comment: You seem to have the first "uploads" folder in the HTML template already (?)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit on the code above and with editing, the code worked :

```
function wp_set_custom_upload_folder( $uploads ) {
    if ( $_FILES['wpua-file'] ) {
        $uploads['path'] = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/avatar';
        $uploads['url'] = site_url( '/' . 'wp-content/uploads/avatar' );
        if ( ! file_exists( $uploads['path'] ) ) {
            mkdir( $uploads['path'], 0755, true );
        }
    }
    return $uploads;
} add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wp_set_custom_upload_folder' );
```